# CRM 2011 some custom reports are not showing any data

Tags: crm

Some SSRS Reports are not working in CRM 2011 but other ssrs reports are working fine. 
Used filtered views in the Query and ran the report with system Administrator role. It is showing no data available but when tried to run in BIDS it is working and also in Report Manager.
Any idea on this issue, Friends. Please suggest some solution if you have any. Thanks!

Comment: Have you compared the working reports to the ones that are not showing any data?  What differences are there between them especially in regards to parameters and dataset queries?

Answer (score 1):

Are you use pre-filtering ? When you run report from CRM, default filter is set to records was created in last 30 days (when you use pre-filtering). Maybe your records are olrder than 30 days and in SQL are visible but not in CRM. Try to change filter during run report.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use shared data source. Just click on your current Data Source and convert to Shared one as below. So instead of embedded, select 'Use Shared datasource reference' and make your connection via windows authentication. This was the way which helped me to show data within CRM!

[image]

[image]

[image]